# How to properly use childs component methods in parent in VUE?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have `ImageUpload.vue` component which is simple Bootstrap modal with few methods.

I'm wondering what is the best way to use one of those methods? Something like this:

```
const app = new Vue({
    components: {
        'component-image-upload': require('./components/ImageUpload.vue'),
    },
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            images: [],
            pagination: {
                previous: null,
                next: null
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        createImage: function(page) {
            this['component-image-upload'].load(image)
        }
    }
});
```

The idea is simply to reuse that model to edit existing image data.

Answer (score 2):

When you find yourself calling methods from another (child) component you should rethink your architecture. Vue components are reusable parts you can use to assemble a view, they are not meant to share javascript logic across your application. If you want to do that you're better off writing a module and importing its functions in your parent Vue file. The way you "communicate" with your child components properly is by prop-bindings, which contain data and can re-trigger the render loop of your child component. Communicating from the child to the parent is done by dispatching events. You never want to share logic between the two.

**Regardless here's how you can do it anyway:**

You have to have an element of your child component in the parent's template, otherwise it wont be mounted and its methods can't be accessed:

```
<component-image-upload ref="image" />
```

Then you can call any method on that component by using its ref:

```
createImage (page) {
  this.$refs.image.myMethod('this is how you call it from parent')
}
```

Comment: yes, i want that image upload modal would be possible to use everywhere in admin section. Can you provide more info about modules?

Comment: It's not quite clear to me why you have an image upload component that doesn't trigger its own logic but needs to be called from outside.

Comment: component is basically a modal. There are already loaded images. When i click on image I want to reuse that  model simply passing there image object.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is [Custom Event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events)

You can trigger any event from your component to the #root element which you have loaded in **vue** instance.

`$emit('event-name')` can be used to trigger the event!!

I hope this helps :)